# Float:right error in CSS

Tags: html, css, google-maps, css-float

I'm learning CSS. I'd love to get a big canvas with Google maps on the left and an input field with two buttons on the right. Now I really don't understand why my code is not doing the job. It draws the canvas with Google maps and puts the input box and the two buttons BELOW it, which is wrong.

**CSS**

```
.floatright {
float:right;
width: 100px;
}
```

**html:**

```
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div class ="floatRight">
     <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 1200px; height: 766px;"></div>
     <div>
      <input id="address" type="textbox">
      <input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeAddress()">
      <input type="button" value="Planes" onclick="Plane()">
    </div>
   </div> 
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS says:

```
.floatright 
{
float:right;
width: 100px;
}
```

Yet, your class is "floatRight".

Classes are case sensitive. "R" is not the same as "r"

Comment: Oh no! I guess I just shouldn't be working in the night...
Well thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

your style should be .floatRight with a capital R.

I would encase the google maps canvas in a div using float:left and then encase the input buttons in a div using float:right.

Answer (score 1):

You should put Right instead of floatright.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are seeing is due to the fact that both the div with an id of "map-canvas" and the following one that contains the inputs are being displayed as "block" (that is the default for a div), and block elements render one after the other vertically. Yo have floated the parent of both containers, but "float" is not inherited, so both render vertically inside their floated parent.

If you want the map and the buttons in the same "line", you need to either float or display as inline both the map's container and the button's one, and make shure that their added widths fit your screen.

for example:

```
#map-canvas {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    float: right;
}

#the-div-that-contains-those-inputs {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
```

Remember to adjust the map's height and width in the html so that it looks good in it's container

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the case sensitive issue the others pointed out , What you really want is float to left, try this:

CSS

```
.floatLeft 
{
float:left;
width: 700px;/*tweak as needed*/
height: 766px;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class ="floatLeft" id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div>
      <input id="address" type="textbox">
      <input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeAddress()">
      <input type="button" value="Planes" onclick="Plane()">
    </div>
```